# Inno-Setup: detect /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES to not show MsgBox in Code

Tags: inno-setup

We are using Inno-Setup with Pascal scripting. Depending on the system, a Yes-No-messagebox is shown. How we can detect the /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES switch to not show the messagebox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in `SuppressibleMsgBox` function (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_suppressiblemsgbox).

Comment: It's worth answering the question, *there is no built-in function nor property that would tell you that the setup runs with /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES command line switch. You would have to inspect the command line.*